# How can I force a page break in LibreOffice, avoiding the last line of the previous page being pulled onto the next when writing a formula

Tags: libreoffice, latex

I prefer LibreOffice to LaTeX. However, I am missing a feature in LibreOffice. When I write an equation almost at the end of a page and I want to add another equation in that case, when I enter a newline, then my last equation also comes down to the next page making an ugly gap at the end of previous page which I do not like.

I want some instruction in Libreoffice like `\newpage` in LaTeX that will help me to split my equation across two pages rather than insisting on keeping them together and moving both to the next page of my document.

How do I do this?

Comment: LibreOffice is a suite of programs. Are you talking about Writer? Did you check your margin settings? Please [edit] these further details into your post. Thaqnk you for helping us help you!

Comment: You may get better answers on https://ask.libreoffice.org/.